# Creating a multi-sig wallet with bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, multi-signature

Our server has bitcoind on it and is running on the test network.

I want to make the wallet multi-signature so no one in our company can withdraw any bitcoin from our server without at least 3 signatures.

Can you do this with bitcoind? I tried to follow: [How can I create a multi signature 2-of-3 transaction?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3712/how-can-i-create-a-multi-signature-2-of-3-transaction) and [How users collectively sign a transaction in a multisig scenario?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51365/how-users-collectively-sign-a-transaction-in-a-multisig-scenario)
.. but could still send the bitcoin from our server with:

```
bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress "address_here" 0.01
```

Comment: That just means you had 0.01 tnBTC in the wallet which didn't come in through the multisig address.

Comment: Is there a way to make the whole wallet multi sig? Instead of just a single address within the whole bitcoind node wallet.

Comment: Just never send any money to it, except through the multisig addresses. There is no way to automatically derive multisig addresses.

Comment: a bit late, but maybe it helps future readers. Whereas you cannot "make the wallet" multisig, you can create a multisig address.  And while you are on testnet, here is a step by step example: https://gist.github.com/gavinandresen/3966071