# How to sign a transaction using multi signature using bitcoind?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, bitcoind, createrawtransaction, signrawtransaction

I created a multisignature address using

```
bitcoin-cli createmultisig 2 '["04A97B658C114D77DC5F71736AB78FBE408CE632ED1478D7EAA106EEF67C55D58A91C6449DE4858FAF11721E85FE09EC850C6578432EB4BE9A69C76232AC593C3B","04019EF04A316792F0ECBE5AB1718C833C3964DEE3626CFABE19D97745DBCAA5198919081B456E8EEEA5898AFA0E36D5C17AB693A80D728721128ED8C5F38CDBA0","04A04F29F308160E6F945B33D943304B1B471ED8F9EACEEB5412C04E60A0FAB0376871D9D1108948B67CAFBC703E565A18F8351FB8558FD7C7482D7027EECD687C"]'
{
    "address" : "38aNB81yPqNp6X2T3rXYZN8Z3C4pSbqEvs",
    "redeemScript" : "524104a97b658c114d77dc5f71736ab78fbe408ce632ed1478d7eaa106eef67c55d58a91c6449de4858faf11721e85fe09ec850c6578432eb4be9a69c76232ac593c3b4104019ef04a316792f0ecbe5ab1718c833c3964dee3626cfabe19d97745dbcaa5198919081b456e8eeea5898afa0e36d5c17ab693a80d728721128ed8c5f38cdba04104a04f29f308160e6f945b33d943304b1b471ed8f9eaceeb5412c04e60a0fab0376871d9d1108948b67cafbc703e565a18f8351fb8558fd7c7482d7027eecd687c53ae"
}
```

Now my address is : 38aNB81yPqNp6X2T3rXYZN8Z3C4pSbqEvs.

I have to send some coins to another address with my address ( created using multisignature). To create a transaction, I have to sign with atleast 2 private keys. Could anyone explain how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you would need to show,us a bit more information, so we can see, how far you got, which steps were taken, etc... this would allow to follow the possible issue. (See also help files here, how to create good questions).

I have two references for you, with solutions for multisig signing:
Here it was [discussed on bitcoin.SE](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51365/how-users-collectively-sign-a-transaction-in-a-multisig-scenario).

And Gavin explained it here [step by step](https://gist.github.com/gavinandresen/3966071) on the testet.
If you have followed the links, let us know how it goes, or where you got stuck, then we can probably help better :-)

Comment: I got it when I went through the links which you shared. Is this the same procedure for all cryptocurrencies which runs on bitcoin core like bitcoin cash, litecoin, dash, doge and bitcoin gold?

Comment: I cannot say, I never worked with these altcoins...